# Plural bei zusammengesetzen Worten mit -liste o. Ä. am Ende

Tags: noun

Welche Schreibweise ist korrekt:

- Telefonnummerliste / Telefonnummer**n**liste
- Dokumentnummerliste / Dokumentnummer**n**liste

Eine Liste kann eine Telefonnummer, aber auch mehrere beinhalten. Gibt es hier eine allgemeine Regel, ob der erste Teil im Plural oder im Singular steht?
Es gibt gebräuchliche Beispiele für beide Arten:

- Ballwagen (nicht Bällewagen)
- Dokumentenablage (nicht Dokumentablage; Google liefert für "Dokumentenablage" ~159.000, für "Dokumentablage" lediglich 21.900 Suchergebnisse)
- Briefablage (nicht Briefeablage)

Comment: Schreib es doch so, wie du es sprichst!

Comment: *Bällebad*. Nicht *Ballbad*. → Es gibt kein System.

Comment: Es gibt einen Dialog von Karl Valentin und Liesl Karlstadt, in dem es darum geht, ob es nicht statt *Semmelknödel* *Semmelnknödeln* heißen muss, weil sie immer aus mehreren Semmeln gemacht werden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Für die Bildung zusammengesetzter Wörter gibt es viele Möglichkeiten, aber keine klaren Regeln, bzw. falls man doch an Regeln glauben möchte: Es gibt erheblich mehr Ausnahmefälle als Regelfälle.

Ich zitiere aus dem Wikipedia-Artikel [Fugenlaut](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) (mit geänderter Formatierung):

> **Bildung zusammengesetzter Wörter**
>
> Bei der Bildung zusammengesetzter Wörter im Deutschen wird das Vorderwort verschiedentlich verändert oder ergänzt:
>
> - Das Vorderwort erscheint als bloßer Wortstamm:
>     *Kronprinz, Seelsorger …*
>     Das fehlende *e* wird gelegentlich als Subtraktionsfuge, subtraktive Fuge, oder Schwundfuge bezeichnet.
> - Das Vorderwort erscheint in seiner vollständigen Einzahlform:
>     *Haustür, Gasthaus …*
> - Das Vorderwort erscheint in seiner Mehrzahlform (mit oder ohne inhaltlichen Anlass):
>     *Kartenhaus, Gänsebraten …*
> - Das Vorderwort erscheint in der Genitiv­form:
>     *Bundesbank, Verkehrszeichen usw.*
>     Diese Fälle sind aus der Zusammenrückung zweier ursprünglich selbständiger Wörter entstanden („des Institúts Diréktor“ → der Institútsdirektor).
> - Ebenso stehen in der Genitivform die Vorderwörter von Bildungen wie
>     *keinesfalls, nötigenfalls usw.*
>     Auch sie sind ursprünglich Zusammenziehungen (aus „keines Fall[e]s“, „nötigen Fall[e]s“ usw.).
> - Schließlich steht manchmal ein reiner Fugenlaut zwischen Vorder- und Hinterwort:
>     *eigentlich, wesentlich,* aber *morgendlich (!), hoffentlich* (aus *hoffend-lich) uvam.
>     Dazu kommen Fälle wie *Mauseloch* u. Ä. All dies entstammt einesteils Aussprache-Erleichterungen oder anderenteils einem „parasitären“ -t (/-d) (wie in „Saf-t“, aus althochdeutsch “saf”).
> - In seltenen Fällen verändert die Dativ­form des Vorderworts nach dem Einfügen des Fugenlautes t seine Gestalt:
>     *meinetwegen, deinetwegen usw.* (aus „von meinentwegen“, „von deinentwegen“ usw.).
> - Das Fugen-s, auch Binde-s genannt, ist der häufigste Fugenlaut und gleicht oft der Genitivform des Vorderworts. Es erscheint jedoch auch bei Wörtern, die gar kein Genitiv-s kennen, beispielsweise
>     *Hochzeitskleid, Liebeslied, Abfahrtszeit, Arbeitsamt.*

Also:
Auch wenn in der Zusammensetzung der erste Teil der Mehrzahlform gleicht, bedeutet das noch lange nicht, dass es für die Mehrzahl einen inhaltlichen Grund gibt. Denn z.B. den oben genannten *Gänsebraten* macht man ja nur aus einem Tier, nicht aus mehreren. Die Bezeichnung *Gansbraten* ist nirgendwo üblich und daher falsch.

Ebenso umgekehrt: Wenn man aus vielen Äpfeln den Saft auspresst, hat man Ende keinen Äpfelsaft, sondern einen Apfelsaft. Extrahiert man dann aus diesem Saft die darin natürlich vorkommende Säure, heißt sie nicht Apfelsäure, sondern [Äpfelsäure](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%84pfels%C3%A4ure).

Und der letzte Punkt aus dem oben zitierten Abschnitt belegt, dass nicht alles was wie ein Genitiv-s aussieht auch wirklich eines ist.

### Fazit

Die Arten, wie Zusammensetzungen gebildet werden, haben zwar manchmal ihren Ursprung in deklinierten Formen des Vorderwortes, aber nicht einmal das stimmt immer. Und wenn es doch der Fall ist, muss deswegen noch lange kein inhalticher Zusammenhang bestehen.

Wortzusammensetzungen sind daher als etwas Eigenständiges anzusehen, und die richtige Art der Zusammensetzung zu finden, folgt leider keinen klaren Regeln, und ist daher ebenso mühsam zu lernen die die Geschlechter der Substantive oder die Fälle der Objekte, die von den Verben verlangt werden.

---

Zu erwähnen ist auch noch, dass es grade bei der Bildung von Zusammensetzungen auch viele regionale Unterschiede gibt. (Im Norden: Schweinebraten, Adventskalender, in Österreich: Schweinsbraten, Adventkalender. Rheinland: Speisenkarte, sonst: Speisekarte)

Auch zu beachten: Ein Gästehaus ist kein Gasthaus, obwohl in beiden mehrere (!) Gäste ein- und ausgehen.

Answer (score 3):

Das "n" in *Telefonnummer**n**liste* drückt keinen Plural aus, ebenso wie das "s" in *Schaden**s**ersatz* kein Genitiv-s ist. Es handelt sich in beiden Fällen um einen sogenannten [Fugenlaut](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut).

Comment: Einspruch! Deine Analyse klingt verführerisch, doch hält sie nicht in allen Fällen Stich. Nimm einen Forscher aus der Pharmakologie, der über das  Wohlergehen seiner Mäuse eine Liste führt. Dieser führt dann eine ***Mäuseliste*** und nicht etwa eine *Mausliste*. Nun mag das ***e*** noch als Fugen-e durchgehen, aber des Umlaut-ä verrät uns, dass das Sprachunbewusste hier eben doch den Plural sieht. (Und sage nicht er führte eigentlich eine *Mauseliste*, von einer solchen habe ich nämlich noch nie gehört. Beim *Mauseschwanz* trifft diese Form zwar auf, aber da ist die Maus ja auch singulär.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Du hast noch nie von einer *Mauseliste* gehört? Du kennst doch sicher den Spruch "die Katze lässt das Mausen nicht", oder?  ;-)

Comment: Siehe auch Orangensaft/Apfelsaft, nicht Äpfelsaft.

Comment: @userunknown: Dabei ist doch offensichtlich, dass in Fruchtsaft immer nur eine Frucht drin ist, selbst im Mehrfruchtsaft. Und auch der Multivitaminsaft enthält nur ein einziges Vitamin. :-)

Comment: @celtschk: nein, er enthält genau ein *Mult*ivitamin ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Das hat wenig mit Plural oder Singular zu tun, oder mit Genitiv--dies scheint mir unergründlich--sondern nunmehr nur noch mit der Phonologie. Die "Dokument-tablage" wäre etwas anderes, was genau weis keiner, steht auch nicht zur Debatte.

Bei Telefonnummerliste verhält es sich ähnlich. Entweder wird das *r* verschluckt, oder ein Hiatus wird nach dem *r* eingefügt, bei dem der Gaumen schließt, so dass ein Gulateraler Verschlusslaut entsteht. Dies klingt nasal, fast wie ein *n*, nur ohne die Zungenspitze. Jedenfalls bei mir, wenn ich es ausprobiere, daher fehlen mir die passenden Fachbegriffe. Eine besondere Betonung des Übergangs von *r* zu *l* fällt flach, da der Ablaut von *Nummer* unbetont ist. Daher ist das scheinbare Plural *-en* durchaus hilfreich für die Aussprache. Dabei kann auch kein gar keinMissverständnis entstehen, da *nl* in Deutsch nicht phonemisch ist. Von Diminutiv "Nummerl, Nummerle" mal ganz zu schweigen.

Natürlich hilft es, dass eine Auflistung mehrer Stellen immer eine Vielzahl enthält.